# What is the point of exporting by ordinal?

Tags: dll, export, dllexport

I can see why someone would want to export by ordinal *only* (i.e. using 'NONAME'), this would reduce the size of the export table and hide some of the details of your DLL's interface
But why would someone bother exporting a function by ordinal as well as by name? As far as I can see this just allows you to explicitly set the ordinal number in the export table.
I know I must be missing something, can someone fill me in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export by ordinal was invented back on Windows 16 where memory was very tight and computers were a lot slower. It uses a lot less memory and does not require all those string comparisons at runtime. The DLLs didn't necessarily even have the symbolic information.